Printer is not printing
I have an Epson XP-2200 wifi printer. It was working.
Yesterday I was not able to print anything with it. I reinstalled the drivers. Looked it up on the internet. No success so far! I use ubuntu 22.04. Ubuntu see it but the printing job stuck processing. Any idea?


This is a wifi only printer!

same meat, different gravy

I tried it. Still not working. Is there any way I can reset my printer?

depends on what you mean by "reset my printer".
